# Is there an event listener for the Devices charms button click?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a windows 8 metro app and want to know if there is any way to listen for the devices charms bar button being selected? I'm trying to come up with a good way to create print page data without having to do it every time content is changed on my page.

I am setting up the share contract event listener right now and noticed there is a DataRequested event that fires when you click the share charms button.

```
DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += MainPage_DataRequested;
```

Is there something similar I can implement for the Devices charms bar button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/20/31-days-of-windows-8-day-20-printing/ for a printing code sample in C#.  You will need code like this:

```
PrintManager manager = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
manager.PrintTaskRequested += manager_PrintTaskRequested;
```

And of course, an implementation of the "manager_PrintTaskRequested" event handler.  See the article for complete details.